# How to find path conditions in KLEE? Ideally, how to find path conditions of longest/shortest paths

Tags: symbolic-math, klee

I am in my dock container exploring the toy "get_sign.c" program that KLEE comes with. I want to explore the different paths of the symbolic calculation executed when I do:

```
clang -I ../../include -emit-llvm -c -g get_sign.c
```

I can see the values the symbolic calculator plugged in via:

```
ktest-tool --write-ints klee-last/test*.ktest
```

However now I would also like to see the actual paths, if there is such an option, or at least I'd like to see the Path conditions corresponding to each path. Finally, I want to be able to see what is the longest/shortest path and explore their path conditions.

I am searching around the klee-last directory and viewing those files, but I don't see any explicit information about path conditions in those .txt files and messages, unless I am and I'm not recognizing them.